# java plugin 3.8 - S2583 false positive

Tags: sonarqube

I think we found a false positive:

```
private static void copy(File from, File to) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    FileChannel src = null;
    FileChannel dst = null;
    try {
        src = new FileInputStream(from).getChannel();
        dst = new FileOutputStream(to).getChannel();
        dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
    } finally {
        if (src != null) {
```

> Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "true"

or do I miss anything?
another example:

```
        if (lastUpdate == null|| lastUpdate != null && lastUpdate.before(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 900000)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually asking question for two different cases :

1. You are hitting a known limitation https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1295 we plan to fix this (hard) one in the next release of java plugin.
2. This one is actually not a false positive at all ! :) if your variable `lastUpdate` is null then the condition is true without evaluating the right hand side of the `||` and if it is false, then `lastUpdate != null` will always evaluate to true so you can actually remove it.

Comment: @1: your link to this question? did you want to link to the jira issue?

Comment: @2  && should have higher precedence than || . so as far as I understand it should be evaluated as

    if (lastUpdate == null|| (lastUpdate != null && lastUpdate.before(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 900000))))

which is the proper way of writing it.

Comment: @1 Fix the link... sorry for that, I was probably still sleepy during my copy paste... :) 

@2 What you say is correct, but second operand will be evaluated only if first one is false ( || is short circuit operator)
You can check with the following example : 
`boolean foo(int i) {
      System.out.println(i);
      return i %2 == 0;
    }
    if( foo(0) || foo(2) && foo(4)) {
      System.out.println("plop");
    }`

It will only print `0 plop`

Comment: ahh ok i see, sorry I was looking at the wrong thing.. so it should be rewritten as
if (lastUpdate == null|| lastUpdate.before(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 900000)))

Comment: Exactly. And this is a case we did not think about when writing the rule. It is really cool to have it flag a nice issue like this. Please upvote and accept asnwer if it helps.

Comment: the first problem really blocks our work flow at the moment. 3.9 is planned for 23.12 right? :/

Comment: I guess I'll have to switch back to 3.7.1

Comment: Why can't you mark the issue as false positive in sonarqube interface ?

Comment: Numerous projects + quite elaborate false positiv workflow + Build breaker plugin leads to a lot of discussion (also about unrelated issues) and emails

Comment: This is exaclty why we tend to think @SonarSource that build breaker is not a good thing: you should rely more on your developers knowledge rather than a tool (but that is a fairly bigger and different discussion).

Comment: Please upvote and accept answer if it helps, Thanks. That is important to make sure this question is closed and will help future user reading this.

Comment: Done. Thanks for your fast response!