# ERROR - Could not complete symbolic execution: reached limit of 10000 steps

Tags: sonarqube

With SonarQube 5.2 when I analyse the same project as I did with SonarQube 5.1.2 I see a lot of such error messages in the log when it analyzes Java sources:

```
ERROR - Could not complete symbolic execution: reached limit of 10000 steps for method updateAll in class DefaultTypeDefinitions
```

These error messages did not appear in former SonarQube 5.1.2 version.

However the analysis result seems to be okay for SonarQube 5.2 in the end.

But these error messages alarm me. I don't understand whats wrong. Can you please help to clarify it?

Comment: We see the same after updating the java plugin to 3.8 today.
Sonar 4.5.6 LTS

Comment: Same here with _5.1.2_ after upgrading java plugin to _3.8_

Comment: As this is something logged by java plugin 3.8 it will happen on every version of SonarQube platform where this version is used.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This error message is actually completely normal and expected when you run your analysis with sonar-java plugin `3.8` because of new symbolic execution engine introduced with this version.

(So in the end this should not be an error message but rather something visible only in debug mode : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1406 this should be fixed in next release of java plugin).

This is harmless to your analysis.

What does it mean ?

For two rules (`S2259` about nullpointer exceptions and `S2583` about conditions always true or false) we use **symbolic execution** which explore all the possible states of a method to find issues. This ends up exploring a big graph of possible states (this is oversimplified here, but sufficient for explanation).

This exploration can be huge and as such there is an arbitrary limit to it : 10 000 steps. So when we cannot complete symbolic execution we log this message.

Concretely: this is a rather indirect way to warn you about some **potential** false negatives about those two rules on this method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, the rule "conditions always true or false" seems to create a lot of false positives. Unfortunately I cannot post an example here since this forum prevents it.

Comment: You can reach us on sonarqube@googlegroups.com to discuss false positive. If it involves try/catch/finally : we are already aware of it see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063605/java-plugin-3-8-s2583-false-positive/34068371?noredirect=1#comment55891107_34068371 and https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1295

Comment: I forgot yesterday where the accept answer button is, now I found it. Yes, at least many of these false positives seem to be related to try/catch/finally. That is a really cool rule, so if it would work perfectly after the fix it would be great.

Comment: surely if it's not an error it shouldn't be logging as ERROR?

Comment: That is why ticket was created and it should be fixed in upcoming version of SonarQube java plugin. Please reread carefully the answer, as I state explicitely that this should not be an error message).