# SonarQube 5.2: a lot of "reached limit of 10000" errors when analyse Java custom rules project by Ant

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.2

I am trying to build and use java custom rules samples from the repository : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/java-custom-rules.

Everything is fine when building and I am able to activate the rules through SonarQube.

However, when running analysis with ant, I have a lot of "error" and at the end, I don't have any issue while there should be a lot.

Error I am having are :

> [sonar:sonar] 08:54:05.985 ERROR - Could not complete symbolic
>   execution: reached limit of 10000 steps for method search in class
>   TestClass [sonar:sonar] 08:54:06.152 ERROR - Could not complete
>   symbolic execution: reached limit of 10000 steps for method method1 in
>   class TestClass

Comment: The errors you mention are not related to the fact that your custom rule is not raising issues : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065727/error-could-not-complete-symbolic-execution-reached-limit-of-10000-steps

Could you double check the quality profile applied to your project contains your custom rule ?

Comment: Yes I already checked this many time and I can see 5 actives rules in my quality profiles.