# How to exclude symblic execution from SonarQube analysis

Tags: sonarqube

During Sonar analysis we have so many exceptions of symbolic execution(Described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065727/error-could-not-complete-symbolic-execution-reached-limit-of-10000-steps)). As far as I know the rules responsible for symbolic execution are S2259 S2583 , so I created a quality profile that exclude these rules but still have excetpions during Sonar analysis. 
We use sonar-maven-plugin for the analysis and I tested with both sonar 6.5 and sonar 6.7 .
How can I exclude symbolic execution from analysis.

Comment: How do you execute the scanner? Please add a screen with project configuration (SonarQube web).

Comment: What version of SonarJava are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Is your project mapped to use the correct quality profile or is it still pointing to the default profile